# Slack Slash Commands event.body returns as string

Tags: javascript, slack

I'm creating my second Slackbot/Slack Slash Command project and everything's been working fine this far, however I tried retrieving the text that user enters after the initial slash command that triggers the bot but the `event.body` gets returned as a string, e.g.

`body: 'token=xxx&team_id=xxx&team_domain=xxx&channel_id=xx&channel_name=privategroup&user_id=U92DLDLKB&user_name=j_b&command=%2Fstanduprota&text=dave&....'`

In the first bot I created I was able to get `event.body.text` without having to do magic with splitting the `event.body` string and turning into a key/value pair array.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: please specify your environment. Is this node.js? are you using an extension to access web requests, e.g. express.

Comment: also check this answer on how to read POST requests with node.js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js